# How to give permissions for all users to execute a program installed by sudoers?

Tags: permissions, software-installation, sudo, users, executable

I installed a Perl program with many external dependencies in /opt/Soft (ubuntu 18 ) using sudo su at first step. Once installed, I exit the "sudo su" mode I could not anymore execute the program as a normal user. How to give permissions for all users to execute a program installed by sudoers? Why after I installed the program with sudo su I could not execute? I can only with sudo

Answer (score -1):

I think you can give other permission for binary you want to execute,

```
chmod o+x /opt/soft/binaryname
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, Can't locate Module.pm in @INC

Comment: sudo /opt/soft/binaryname, it works, but not all users are sudoers

Comment: all Perl modules are installed under  /root/.local/share/.cpan/ , this installation was not system-wide. I know the problem but not the solution

Comment: Can you try su to root, then check env root $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then export the output to user environment. But if the path is under root owner, you still cannot use.

Comment: echo $PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: echo  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty

Comment: I could not make a symbolic link between directories /home/user and /root/.local/share/.cpan